# The trait bound `String: From<&T>` is not satisfied when my T is bound with Into<String>

Tags: string, rust, type-conversion, traits

I have the following code,

```rust
impl<T: Debug + Into<String> + Clone> TryFrom<Vec<T>> for Positionals {
  type Error = &'static str;
  fn try_from(mut vec: Vec<T>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
    let mystr: String = vec.get(0).unwrap().into();
```

And that code is producing this error,

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `String: From<&T>` is not satisfied
  --> bin/seq.rs:21:43
   |
21 |         let mystr: String = vec.get(0).unwrap().into();
   |                                                 ^^^^ the trait `From<&T>` is not implemented for `String`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<String>` for `&T`
help: consider introducing a `where` bound, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
```

I'm confused as to why this is generating an error because I have a trait bound on `Vec<T>` such that `T` must implement `Into<String>`, what else is required? I don't understand why this is, I remove the `into()`, I get

```
let mystr: String = vec.get(0).unwrap();
           ------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `String`, found `&T`
```

How can I get my `T` in `Vec<T>` to `String`? The reason why I'm doing `Vec<T>` and not `Vec<String>` is because I want to support `Vec<&str>` too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your vector gives you *references*, i.e. `&String`. While `Into<String>` is trivially implemented for `String`, it is not implemented for `&String`, which would require cloning. You could implement the compiler's suggestion and add a `where T: From<&String>`, but it'd require additional fiddling with lifetimes and would again not support `&str`.

To support both `&str` and `String`, you can use `AsRef<str>`:

```
impl<T: Debug + Clone + AsRef<str>> TryFrom<Vec<T>> for Positionals {
    type Error = &'static str;
    fn try_from(mut vec: Vec<T>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let mystr: String = vec[0].as_ref().into();
        todo!()
    }
}
```

With that both of the following compile:

```
Positionals::try_from(vec!["foo",]);
Positionals::try_from(vec!["foo".to_owned(),]);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6947290b446e2967a0fa9528a2908188)

Side note: you can use `vec[0]` instead of `vec.get(0).unwrap()`. (To prevent an unwanted move out of the vector, just add a borrow, i.e. `&vec[0]`.)

Comment: Why doesn't the into method work, out of curiosity? Why do I get the error above when T supports `Into<String>`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Because `Into<String>` is (trivially) defined for `String`, but you have `&String` because you're referring to the existing item in the vector. (I've now amended the answer to mention that.)